# Dependency conflict using MVC6 in ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependencies, entity-framework-6

Could this be a dependency conflict? I am getting error. I have tried changing the dependencies but it still retrns these errors, please I need your supports.
This is the project.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8"
  },
```

This is the StartUp.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;

using MyQuotesApps.models;
using Microsoft.Framework.Runtime;
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;

namespace MyQuotesApps
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<QuotesAppContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]));
        }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appenv) {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appenv.ApplicationBasePath);
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("config.json");
            configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

This is returning the below error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.IConfigurationProvider'  MyQuotesApps.DNX 4.5.1, MyQuotesApps.DNX Core 5.0   C:\Users\ken4ward\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MyQuotesApps\src\MyQuotesApps\Startup.cs    28  Active
Error   CS1061  'EntityOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer' and no extension method 'UseSqlServer' accepting a first argument of type 'EntityOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   MyQuotesApps.DNX 4.5.1, MyQuotesApps.DNX Core 5.0   C:\Users\ken4ward\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MyQuotesApps\src\MyQuotesApps\Startup.cs    24  Active
```

Answer (score 0):

You must migrate to ASP.net Core 1.0.You'll be in big trouble if you're still using beta packages.So start to migrate or create a new project with the latest packages.

Here you can see how to Migrate : [**Migration**](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/index.html)

Or start from the latest .Net core : [**.Net Core 1.0**](https://www.microsoft.com/net)

[**Getting started with ASP.NET Core MVC and Visual Studio**](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc.html)

Comment: Could you kindly share howTo? I'm not a .Net person. Elaborate by adding code snippets.

Comment: your problem is not related to your code.it's an issue on your framework.so you have to upgrade it to more stable and latest versions.Hence you're new to the .net,I would like to recommend to start a new project with the latest frameworks. please follow the link (i.e. Getting started with ASP.NET Core MVC and Visual Studio ) which I have added on my post above.